# Is there a way to get data from user using browser's console

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to capture user's input through browser's console.
Currently I get input using JS's prompt, like so:

```
var a = prompt("Enter your numbers").split(",");
console.log(a);
```

But I would like data to be entered through the console.
Is there a way to do this with Javascript or Typescript?

EDIT

John Weisz gave good answer, this would normally work, it won't work with my problem.

You see, the user will use the console to enter a string of numbers which I will store into an array and check for duplicates...

Then print those duplicates with an object to the console...

```
var a; 
window.cliApi = { 
setValue: function (value) { 
a = value;
} 
} 
var counts = {}; 

a.forEach(function(x){ 
counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) +1; }); 

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: which console? Chrome or command line?

Comment: Since browser console is a REPL tool, my guess is "no, not possible".

Comment: Through the Chrome console...

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `console.log` before `cliApi.setValue` could be possible called. `console.log` is ran immediately when your code opens. `setValue` only runs when you call it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of. You can create a globally exposed API that the user can use from the console, for example:

```
var a;

window.cliApi = {
    setValue: function (value) {
        a = value;
    },
    getValue: function () {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Then, in the browser console, you can type:

> cliApi.setValue("hello world")

After which your variable will be populated.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ww8vu5o9/3/).

*Note, that with JSFiddle, you will need to set the console scope to the `result` frame instead of `top` (you do this inside your dev tools), as your code is running inside a frame. This is not required if you host your code yourself (and not from a frame).*

Comment: I hope I am not asking too much, but if the user would enter data through the console in a way you described how would you save it in a variable so you could use it, like with prompt I wrote above?

Comment: @prius Sure, it's no big deal, you can simply assign to a variable instead of doing an `alert`. Note, however, that your variable won't be populated _until_ `cliApi.setValue` is called. That is, you can't just call `console.log(a)` straight away, but only _after_ `cliApi.setValue` was called.